# Change sweet alert text on the existing alert after pressing OK

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

so I want to change the text on the existing alert after I press on OK. The modal closes after I click on any button. Rather than having to throw a new alert, can we prevent the modal from closing and change the existing text? Can we do it using PreConfirm?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

So I was able to figure out a way of doing it. I used a setTimeout to delay the modal from closing for a few seconds and directly used their ID's to modify their content. If there is any other way of doing the same do let me know. Thanks .

```js
 swal({
              title: "title",
              text: "text goes here.",
              closeOnEsc: false,          
              closeModal: false,
     preConfirm: () => {
                   return new Promise((resolve) => {
              
                 $("#swal2-title").text("New title")
                  $("#swal2-content").text("new text")
                  setTimeout(() => {
                  console.log("Doing async operation");
                resolve()
              }, 5000)
             })
            },
            allowOutsideClick: () => !swal.isLoading()
            }).then( isConfirm => { 
            //code for after a confirmation
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing your code, but you can always implement your own version of an alert box as a modal and replace string inside it. You can also check SweetAlerts github issues (I'm guessing you're trying to use it after googling "PreConfirm javascript"). Have you seen this topic? [SweetAlert github issue](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/896)

Comment: , yes I did try this out . It does throws a normal alert , which once you press closes both the alerts. I kinda wanted something to stop the swal from closing on any button press and change the text on it.